Will pass access token via LWC flagged as Security Issue
while working on the Security Review Issue, I wanted to clarify our approach. We've built LWC components using our React code. In React, we call our backend API using fetch.
To obtain the access token, we're using Named Credentials. We then call our backend to exchange the Salesforce token for our token, which is subsequently passed to the LWC component and set localStorage
Could you advise if this approach is flagged as a violation?

That would allow access to the token in the context of the client which is far less secure than routing interactions through the Salesforce server side. I would be uncomfortable taking this approach myself, as someone working on AppExchange packages, and I would expect this to cause me trouble during a security review. I recommend you request a Security Team Office Hours to discuss with them, or avoid taking this approach client-side. You could use the free provider partition platform cache, assuming you're creating an app exchange listed package, to hold the token in session-related storage.
